# how to add a CSS class using a Macro expression?

Tags: kentico

I need help setting up a CSS drop-down using macro. I created a new field, and under the data type I selected the dropdown. now back under transformation i paste the new field inside the class selector, but i dont see any of the class names i typed under form control.

```
   <div class="alert {% AlertCssBackground %}" > <div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored the class name in the database field `fieldName` and you are using ascx page format then you can type `<%# Eval("fieldName") %>` in your transformation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you need to verify:

1. The drop-down field values are in the format

`<value>;<display text>`

For example:

`red-bg;Red background`
`green-bg;Green background`

What is stored in the database is the value. Which will be either `red-bg` or `green-bg`.

2. In your transformation, make sure you're using the proper type.  If you're using macro syntax `{% fieldName %}` then you need to make sure you're using the Text/Html transformation type.  If you're using the ascx format type `<%# Eval("fieldName") %>` then you need to use the ASCX transformation type.